# JSF Richfaces Render condition for one part of Label

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, label, render

I am using three different strings from a backing bean to build a label for a rich:simpleTogglePanel.

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel id="loadPanel" switchType="client" label="#{backingbean.name1} - #{backingbean.name2} - #{backingbean.name3}" >
```

I want the name3 to appear only in some specific conditions. Is it possible to give a condition only to name3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using the EL conditional operator:

```
label="#{backingbean.name1} - #{backingbean.name2} - #{conditions ? backingbean.name3 : ''}"
```

So when the `conditions` evaluate to `true` then `backingbean.name3` is printed otherwise just an empty string is added to the label, so `backingbean.name3` will be omitted when `conditions` evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel id="loadPanel" switchType="client" 
        label="#{backingbean.name1} - #{backingbean.name2} #{condition ? ' - ' : ''} #{condition ? backingbean.name3 : ''}" >
```

that `'-'` will display without reason

Comment: So just use `(' - ').concat(backingbean.name3)` instead of checking condition two times.